# Google Script doc.getBody() returns plain text

Tags: google-apps-script

Just a quick question, is there anyway that I can get the body of my google doc to be as exact as it is? For example, I have a bold sentence in my google doc, but whenever i'm trying to send it using via sendEmail in google script, it's being sent as plaint text, the bold letters an other formatted texts are being converted into plain, please see my code:

```
  var body_hw1 = doc_hw1.getBody().getText();
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject_hw1, body_hw1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `getBody()` returns an object that is not usable outside of Google Docs. The method `getText()` returns plain text.

In order for use bold fonts, etc, in an email, it has to be formatted as HTML. So you need to convert Google document to HTML. There is no built-in function for this, but a third-party solution is available: it does not support full range of Docs format but certainly supports bold and italic fonts, and similar. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47313357).

Comment: Thank you so much for y our respond, @if.. Will definitely check this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to extract the plain text and format it into html yourself and send that. For example:

```
   var myText = {header:'Dear sir,',message:'We are writing to inform you...'}

   var message = ("<h3>"+ myText.header +"</h3>" +
                 "<p>"+ myText.message +"</p>")

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Important Message', message);
```