# Google Apps Script - Docs. Converting table cells with formatting to HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm creating a Google Script add-on in Docs (not Sheets) which allows people to input content into predefined table cells, which I then later on need to parse and turn into HTML.

I'm almost there, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47313357/2586977 and the [GoogleDoc2HTML](https://github.com/oazabir/GoogleDoc2Html) script it mentions. I can get out everything I need, except for the simple formatting that some content will require – bold, italics and links.

The method described in the linked article uses `getTextAttributeIndices()` to work out where these attribute changes are located, then splices the corresponding HTML tags into the output to replicate the formatting. It's kind of long-winded, but it works!

The problem I have is that `getTextAttributeIndices()` will only work on `[Text][2]` elements, and I'm trying to get the indices of content in a `[TableCell][3]` element.

The console gives me the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getTextAttributeIndices in object TableCell.

If do `myTableCell.getText()` first, I lose all the formatting.

Comment: [Check the reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/). There are probably methods on the `TableCell` instance that allow you to retrieve the cell's attributes.

Comment: There is certainly `TableCell.getAttributes()` but the result from that only apply to the whole cell, and there isn't a corresponding method to get the attribute indices. In my case, the content in the cell won't be all bold, or all italic, or all one link, but a block of text potentially containing all of those mixed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@axemonkey Your solution will work but it's brittle since the documentation does not guarantee that the paragraph element will always be a child element at index 0. Rummaged through the documentation and found this method:

[`TabelCell::findElement(elementType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#findElement(ElementType))

You can use that method to fetch child elements of a given type. It returns a [`RangeElement`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element) which wraps the child element so you have to call the following method:

[`RangeElement::getElement()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getElement())

---

So using the above, a more reliable way to get the paragraph element is this:

```
var paragraph = tableCell.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH).getElement();
```

To get the [`Text`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) element in the paragraph you can use `findElement()` on the paragraph instance as well:

```
var text = paragraph.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT).getElement();
```

So bringing it all together you'd get:

```
var paragraph = tableCell.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH).getElement();
var text = paragraph.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT).getElement();

var indices = text.getAttributeIndices();
```

There's more code to write, but you'll have more readable code and its less likely break since it does not rely on child indices.

---

PS: When you invoke the `getElement()` method on a `RangeElement` its returns the element, but as far as the Apps Script GUI is concerned you only get auto-completion for properties associated with the [`Element`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element) interface. If you want to get auto-completion for the properties and methods specific to a given element type, then leverage one of the many type casting methods defined in the Element interface. These methods are always prefixed with `as`. So to get code-completion for the text element you could write code like this:

```
var text = paragraph.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT).getElement().asText();
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I had a feeling my solution could be improved, but I just couldn't see the wood for the trees any more. Cheers!

Comment: @axemonkey Here's a trick I use when I get to that point...just skim the official reference documentation - don't look for anything too specific - just peruse Class and Functions descriptions that pertain to a given built-in service (Document, Spreadsheet, Form etc.) and see what jumps out at you...You'd be surprised at how effective this is.

Comment: One thing I found when I implemented this, is that the `findElement()` calls don't find `PARAGRAPH` or `TEXT` – I needed to use the full `DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH` and `DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT` inside the parentheses. But it's working now, and more readable and sturdy. Thanks again!

Comment: You're correct. Updated my response accordingly...and added a little extra in the process.

Comment: Awesomeness. Thanks for the help! 

Answer (score 2):

I finally cracked it, so I'm sharing the answer in case anyone else runs into this.

`getTextAttributeIndices()` only works on `Text` elements, not `TableCell` elements.

BUT it turns out that when you create a `TableCell` element and enter content into it, it implicitly creates a `Paragraph` element and that contains a `Text` element.

Therefore this does NOT work:

> `myTableCell.getTextAttributeIndices()`

but this DOES work:

> `myTableCell.getChild(0).getChild(0).getTextAttributeIndices()`